# Bat script to find and replace files in multiple subfolders - replace .java files with .class files from specific folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, windows-scripting

I am new to windows batch scripting .. please help on this scenario

I have file structures as below ::

**dir1**:
c:\workspace\changeset\com\folder

**subfolder1**

- one.java

**subfolder-2**

- two.java

**dir2**:
c:\workspace\target\class\com\folder

**subfolder1**

- one.class

**subfolder2**

- two.class

**Subfolder3**

- three.class

Need to find and replace  **dir1** files in respective subfolders i.e one.java and two.java from **dir2** files i.e one.class and two.class ( need to replace certain .java files with .class files from specific folder )

much appreciated for your help.

Thanks 
Arjun

Comment: post what you have done so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d "c:\workspace\changeset\com\folder\*.java"') do (
 if exist "c:\workspace\target\class\com\folder\%%~na.class" (
  echo copy "c:\workspace\target\class\com\folder\%%~na.class" "c:\workspace\changeset\com\folder\%%a")
)
```

The required COPY commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO COPY` to `COPY` to actually copy the files. Append `>nul` to suppress report messages (eg. `1 file copied`)

Note that execution directly from the prompt and as lines with a batch file are different. The `metavariable` (loop-control variable) `%%x` must be referenced as `%%x` for a batch line and `%x` if executed from the command prompt. Since it makes little sense to repeatedly execute a line containing a `for` from the prompt (it's easier to create a batch file), I post the batch-file version. User's responsibility to adjust for direct-from-prompt if desired.

Read each filename in `/b` basic form `/a-d` without directories and assign the filename+extension to `%%a`.

If a file in the other directory called *thenamepartofthefile*.class exists, then copy *that* file to the first directory.

---

Please post the **entire** problem to be solved. The approach can change radically, as in this case.

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir1=U:\sourcedir\changeset"
SET "sourcedir2=U:\sourcedir\target"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /s /a-d "%sourcedir1%\*.java" '
 ) DO (
 SET "javadir=%%~dpa"
 SET "classfile=!javadir:%sourcedir1%=%sourcedir2%!%%~na.class"
 IF EXIST !classfile! ECHO COPY "!classfile!" "%%a"
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir1` and `sourcedir2` to suit your circumstances.

Essentially, the same approach and the same comments re messages. The difference is that this procedure uses files and subdirectories in the `dir` list and substitutes the first part of the directoryname in deriving the expected name of the `.class` file.

Comment: Thank you Magoo .. I have another query .. like if we have subfolder within dir 1 and dir 2. Then how to serach for .Java and .Class file and copy them to respective folder ...